# FDA APIs have data discrepancies

Tags: data-request, api, medical, openfda

FDA APIs have data discrepancies. Last month and current month, I ran APIs for getting values using the below APIs, but the results were different. Last month it showed 500+ records for my filter, but this month it reduced to 250+ (February month data).The UI showing 500+ records

[https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[20230201+TO+20230228]&limit=100](https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:%5B20230201+TO+20230228%5D&limit=100)

Answer (score 1):

At times the FDA releases corrections for previously released data, which may result in fewer records than seen previously.

Regards,

Violet Wren, openFDA Tech Lead

Comment: But for the June month I'm not getting the results. Its showing No match found Endpoint-https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:%5B20230601+TO+20230620%5D&limit=100 {
  "error": {
    "code": "NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "No matches found!"
  }
}

Comment: That endpoint is updated Quarterly, so the June data was not available at that point (it is now).